# Questions Regarding DateTime and System.Data.SQLite

Tags: vb.net, system.data.sqlite

To populate my database I have been using the builtin SQLite command for datetime:

```
INSERT INTO samples (timestamp, sample_value) Values(datetime('now','localtime'), ...)
```

When I look at this on my Mac using a SQLite Reader called Base I see the following timestring:

```
2011-06-20 13:18:14
```

When I debug my vb.net program this line:

```
ts2 = CStr(r("timestamp"))
```

gives me

```
6/20/2011 1:18:14 PM
```

To parse this I have been using:

```
 ts = DateTime.ParseExact(ts2, "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", _
                                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

This works for readings at 12:00:00 PM, but once I get to 1 PM I get a System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is this a UI formatting difference between PC and Mac? What might be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `h` opposed to  `H` in your format string. Try `"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`

`h` is is 12 hour format while `H` is used in 24 hour format and your string `6/20/2011 1:18:14 PM` requires `h.`

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx)